# Phonegap ui-router ui-view not working with angular 1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, phonegap

I am trying to port my Angular 1.5 website into a phonegap application.

It seems to be working on my web browser perfectly fine but on phonegap, the ui-view sub views don't show up.

Does anybody have any idea why or how I can solve this?

This is the header piece with the meta data for my phonegap app :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
<!-- This is a wide open CSP declaration. To lock this down for production, see below. -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" />
<!-- Good default declaration:
* gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
* https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
* Disables use of eval() and inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
    * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
    * Enable eval(): add 'unsafe-eval' to default-src
* Create your own at http://cspisawesome.com
-->
 <!--<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: 'unsafe-inline' https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" />-->

<!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />-->
<title>Exotic Vehicle Services</title>
<meta name="description" content="exotic car rental source" />
<meta name="keywords" content="rent exotic cars" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/assets/animate.css/animate.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/assets/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/jquery/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/jquery/jquery-timepicker-jt/jquery.timepicker.css" type="text/css" />

<!--<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Play" rel="stylesheet">-->
<!--<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>-->

<!-- build:css css/app.min.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ngfader.css" type="text/css">
<!-- endbuild -->

</head>
```

This is my main div inside the body that has the `ui-view` attribute.

```
<div class="app" id="app" ng-class="{'app-header-fixed':app.settings.headerFixed, 'app-aside-fixed':app.settings.asideFixed, 'app-aside-folded':app.settings.asideFolded, 'app-aside-dock':app.settings.asideDock, 'container':app.settings.container}" ui-view></div>
```

My angular is being bootstrapped manually `onDeviceReady` event. It runs the following code :

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    console.log('Received Device Ready Event');
    console.log('calling setup push');
    //app.setupPush();
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        if (window.cordova) {
            console.log("Running in Cordova, will bootstrap AngularJS once 'deviceready' event fires.");
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
                console.log("Deviceready event has fired, bootstrapping AngularJS.");
                angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['app']);
            }, false);
        } else {
            console.log("Running in browser, bootstrapping AngularJS now.");
            angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['app']);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you include the code that you think is the problem spot?

Comment: I just updated it with some code, I'm not sure if it has something to do with security settings for a mobile device as this is my first phonegap app